# why does the element in my Javascript code not stop moving after it reaches 200px?

Tags: javascript, html, css

the "voila" element in my code won't stop after reaching 200px?
what is the problem in the logic of the code?
and how do I make it work.

```js
var voila = document.querySelector(".voila");
voila.textContent = "hahahaha";
voila.style.position = "absolute";


setInterval(function() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(voila).getPropertyValue("left"));
  if (left >= 0) {
    voila.style.left = left + 2 + "px";
  } else if (left <= 200) {
    voila.style.left = left - 10 + "px";
  }
}, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="voila"></div>
```

any help?

Comment: the first problem with this code is that you can't test it  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `(left>=0)` is always `true` since you keep adding a positive number to left so the part `} else if (left<=200) {` will never be reached. try `if(left<200) `

Comment: You might also be interested in CSS keyframe animation https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/187054

Comment: Keyframes animation would be suitable for this as others have mentioned, but if you stick with setInterval it should be cleared when it’s not needed any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you wanted to do this.

```js
var voila = document.querySelector(".voila");
voila.textContent = "hahahaha";
voila.style.position = "absolute";


setInterval(function() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(voila).getPropertyValue("left"));
  if (left >= 0 && left <= 200) {
    voila.style.left = left + 2 + "px";
  }
}, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="voila"></div>
```

And the `css` way of doing it (works better)

```css
.voila {
  x-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: anim 1.7s infinite;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="voila">ABC</div>
```

Comment: I like the CSS way :)

Comment: Most developers use the CSS Way

Comment: Their original code had one way animation 5 times faster than the other....

Answer (score 0):

this part  `else if (left <= 200)` is non sens

you can do that:

```js
const voila = document.querySelector('.voila');
voila.textContent    = 'hahahaha';
voila.style.position = 'absolute';
voila.mov = { pos: 0, min: 0, max:200, stepOn: 2, stepBack: -10, step: 2 }


setInterval(() =>
  {
  voila.mov.pos += voila.mov.step

  if (voila.mov.pos >= voila.mov.max) voila.mov.step = voila.mov.stepBack
  if (voila.mov.pos <= voila.mov.min) voila.mov.step = voila.mov.stepOn
 
  voila.style.left = `${voila.mov.pos}px`
  }, 10)
```

```css
* {
  padding : 0;
  margin  : 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="voila"></div>
```

You can also use [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)

```js
const voila  = document.querySelector('.voila')
 
voila.textContent    = 'hahahaha';
voila.style.position = 'absolute';
voila.mov = { pos: 0, min: 0, max:200, stepOn: 2, stepBack: -10, step: 2 }

function movInOut()
  {
  voila.mov.pos += voila.mov.step

  if (voila.mov.pos >= voila.mov.max) voila.mov.step = voila.mov.stepBack
  if (voila.mov.pos <= voila.mov.min) voila.mov.step = voila.mov.stepOn

  voila.style.left = `${voila.mov.pos}px`

  requestAnimationFrame(movInOut)
  }
requestAnimationFrame(movInOut)
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="voila"></div>
```